# C wrapper to errno

Tags: c, wrapper, errno

I've written the function to wrap an errno, but I have compile error: 
error: ‘EACCES’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         case EACCES:
What I'm doing wrong? How can I wrap the errno with switch-case?
status_t defined as enum of relevant errors.

```
static status_t GetErrorStatus (int errno_value)
    {
        status_t err_status = COMMON_ERROR;

        switch (errno_value) 
        {
            case EACCES: 
                err_status = NO_ACCESS_PERMISSION;
                break;
            case EPERM:
                err_status = NO_ACCESS_PERMISSION;
                break;
            case EIDRM:
                err_status = SEMAPHORE_REMOVED;
                break;
            case ENOENT:
                err_status = FILE_DOESNT_EXIST;
                break;
            case EEXIST:
                err_status = SEMAPHORE_ALREADY_EXISTS;
                break;

            default: err_status = COMMON_ERROR;
        }
        return (err_status);
    }
```

Comment: Show some [MCVE] please.

Comment: Why copy `errno` values to what looks like an enum or another set of macros representing integral values?

Comment: @GovindParmar I can think of 2 useful reason: grouping of errors as done above with `EACCES, EPERM` into `NO_ACCESS_PERMISSION` and allowing a desired sequent index or bit mask of error identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show a complete code.

My guess is that **you forgot to `#include <errno.h>`** or that on your particular system `EACCESS` is not defined.

On Linux, read [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).  `EACCESS` is mentioned as POSIX, so on some non-POSIX systems it might not be defined.

The C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) mentions `errno` in its §7.5 and `EACCESS` is not listed there. If it exists, it should be a macro, so you might wrap some appropriate part of your code with `#ifdef EACCESS` ... `#endif`

Comment: "you forgot to #include <errno.h>"   - You are absolutely right!!! I've added it and now compiler is quiet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> How can I wrap the `errno` with switch-case?

Not all platforms support the various errors.  C specifies only 3: `EDOM EILSEQ ERANGE` in `<errno.h>` and, importantly, they are *macros*.  I'd expect additional platform specific errors to also be so testable.

```
    switch (errno_value) 
    {
        #ifdef EACCES
        case EACCES: 
            err_status = NO_ACCESS_PERMISSION;
            break;
        #endif
        #ifdef EPERM
        case EPERM:
            err_status = NO_ACCESS_PERMISSION;
            break;
        #endif
        ...
```